# multidimentional array with ng-repeat in ionic v1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-v1

I have a json in which I am getting search result with multiple arrays:

[image: JSON array which I am getting from server]

After this you can see in the below image that I am getting another array with index [0-20] which actually consist of data I want to display:

[image: Actual data array]

with single ng-repeat it does not seems to be possible I guess and after struggling a lot I am here to ask help.

```
<ul vertilize-container class="grid-menu-list">
    <li vertilize class="grid-menu-item explore" ng-repeat="trending in trendings">

    <p class="item-title">Title</p>
    <p class="sub-title">{{trendings.title}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I am working on ionic v1. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

Js file

```
$scope.data = {
blog : [],
---
trending : [
----- ]
}
```

HTML file

```
<ul vertilize-container class="grid-menu-list">
    <li vertilize class="grid-menu-item explore" ng-repeat="t in trending">

    <p class="item-title">Title</p>
    <p class="sub-title">{{t.title}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Trending again has an array with in .. please check my JSON.

Comment: please add some json here

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 `ng-repeat` to achieve the desired result. Here is the sample code. You can use any tag you would prefer for markup. (For convenience I used simple `div` tag with some styling ).

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <span> {{key}} </span>
  <div ng-repeat="eachValue in value">
   <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Name: {{eachValue.name}} </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have used dummy data for example. Just use your data with appropriate property names to get the desired result. Here is the working example. https://codepen.io/next1/pen/jKQpLV